# Powershell script to indexof value from array

Tags: powershell

The below command will print out a list of string

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "mc.exe admin policy list $target" -OutVariable policiesList | Out-Null
```

In the powershell script, there is a prompt to enter some value

```
$option = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter option: "
```

I wanted to keep prompting the "Read-Host" to capture user value until the value (in $option ) matches in the policiesList.
I have tried using the IndexOf, but it returns -1 even though the $option matches one of the value in policiesList

```
$rr=[array]::IndexOf($policiesList , $option)
echo $rr
```

The below is my entire script

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "mc.exe admin policy list $target" -OutVariable policiesList | Out-Null
$option=""
$i=[Array]::IndexOf($policiesList, $option) 
while($i -eq -1){
    $i=[Array]::IndexOf($policiesList, $option) 
    $option = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter option"
}
```

Comment: Why not just use $policiesList = Invoke-Expression -Command "mc.exe admin policy list $target" - that'd save having to use Out-Null
Also, what is the type of $policiesList? Use $policiesList.GetType() to find out as very often a data type that would appear to be an array is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Note: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Therefore, reformulate your call to `mc.exe` as follows:

```bash
# Saves the output lines as an array in $policies.
$policies = mc.exe admin policy list $target
```

Note that `[Array]::IndexOf()` uses case-*sensitive* lookups, which may be why the lookups don't succeed.
A case-*insensitive* approach that is also simpler is to use PowerShell's [`-in`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin). (Note that the comparison value must match an array element *in full* either way.)

```bash
do {
  $option = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter option"
} while ($option -notin $policies)
```

Note that `-in` returns `$true` or `$false`, i.e. *whether* the element was found in the collection, not the *index* at which the element was found.

However, in your case this is sufficient.

In cases where you do need to know the index in combination with case-*insensitive* lookups, you can use `[Array]::FindIndex()`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60254562/45375).